# ¿Como persistir datos entre fragments Navigation Bottom?

Tags: android

Estoy usando lo nuevo de navigation component de Android JetPack, lo que sucede es que cuando entro al fragment A, este consume un servicio y al obtener la respuesta puede que pase al fragment B  o puede que me que de en el A, pero cuando paso al fragment B y hago click hacia atrás, se vuelve a consumir el servicio del fragment A y me vuelve a llevar al fragment B. ¿Cual seria la mejor forma para que no se vuelva a consumir el servicio cuando estoy navegando hacia atrás?

Comment: ¿Cómo notificas que se haga la navegación al obtener la respuesta del servicio? En función de ésto te podemos dar una respuesta que encaje mejor con lo que necesitas e incluso evitar volver a ejecutar el servicio si no se ha prevenido.

Comment: Hola, gracias por comentar,  cuando se inicia el fragmentA se consume el servicio en el onViewCreate(), si doy click a un boton este me lleva al fragmentB, una vez estando en el fragmentB y doy click hacia atras, al estar en el fragmentA se hace el consumo del servicio nuevamente.

Comment: Prueba a ejecutar el servicio en el onCreate, ya que el Fragment recrea la vista y siempre irá al onCreateView (es un método para crear la vista).  El onViewCreated puedes usarlo para hacer el populate y la carga de datos en el onCreate.